# Flutter SQL: how to add SQL table into SQL table in Flutter

Tags: sql, database, flutter, dart

I want to create a flutter flashcard app and store the flashcards data into a SQL database.

In order to achieve that, I created 3 class models, with one nested by another one:

| Class | Var 1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **CardSide** | title (type: String) | content (type: String) |
| `Card` | frontSide (type: **CardSide**) | backSide (type: **CardSide**) |
| CardSet | name (type: String) | cards (type: List<`Card`>) |

For each side of a card, there are "title" and "content" stored into CardSide class.

For each card, there are "frontSide" and "backSide" stored into Card class.

For each cards set, there are "name"(name of card set) and "cards"(a list of Cards) stored into CardSet class.

So, with 3 classes created, I started to write codes to create 3 SQL tables and try to store tables into tables, creating a nested structure. However, I realized the packages that I find on pub dev do not support format of "tables", which only support things like "strings" and "int".

In firebase, it is possible to store database inside database, but it seems that sqlite does not support that.

Therefore, Is there anyone can provide me solution to store these flashcard data? Like recommendations of offline database (using SQL if possible), suggestions of packages, the way to store it, crud method etc. It would be great if source code examples can be provided, thank you!